# Chaining complex queries using ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Let's suppose I have a rails model, Table, with methods location,a1,a2,a3

I have a postgresql query of the form

```
SELECT avg(val) FROM (
    SELECT unnest(array[a1,a2,a3]) as val FROM table WHERE location = 'USA') alias;
```

Which I would like to undertake using activerecord, rather than as raw SQL, mainly because I would like to be able to split the query so it's chainable, along the lines of:

```
Table.where(location: 'USA').select(...)
```

(The reason for this is that I'd like to move the postgresql query above into the model as a method.)

Is there any way this can be done?

Comment: unnest? what? what exactly are you trying to do? in case there is no better way to write that query, you should leave it in raw SQL.

Comment: the unnest(array(... takes a1,a2,a3 and creates a setof integers, that the built in postgres aggregate functions (avg, stddev_samp etc) can be used against

Answer (score 4):

`Table.from( 
  Table.where(location: 'USA').select('unnest(array[a1,a2,a3]) as val'),
  'subquery_name' 
).average('subquery_name.val')`

Now, for you to understand what the above query is doing, please study the following `ActiveRecord` methods:

1. [from(value, subquery_name = nil)](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-from)
2. [average(column_name, options = {})](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-average)